# Sharepoint public site issue on Android

Tags: android, sharepoint

Someone decided to use Sharepoint to build a public website.  The website is content only and does not use any of the Sharepoint document library or collaboration features.  The website is public facing, requires no login and uses SSL.

The site looked good when viewed from a computer browser, however when viewing on Android Chrome it will prompt the user to install a security certificate.  The message is this:

> No Certificates found
>
> The app Chrome has requested a certificate.  Choosing a certificate will let the app use this identity with servers now and in the future.  The app has identified the requesting server as , but you should only give the app access to the certificate if you trust the app.

I believe this is due to Android has no default user certificate installed and Sharepoint wants one to identify the user.  Is there anyway to reconfigure Sharepoint so it will NOT request a client certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) speaks a lot about this. Particularly the paragraph that seems important is

> > Unknown certificate authority
> >     In this case, the SSLHandshakeException occurs because you have a CA that isn't trusted by the system. It could be because you have a certificate from a new CA that isn't yet trusted by Android or your app is running on an older version without the CA. More often a CA is unknown because it isn't a public CA, but a private one issued by an organization such as a government, corporation, or education institution for their own use.
> >     Fortunately, you can teach HttpsURLConnection to trust a specific set of CAs. The procedure can be a little convoluted, so below is an example that takes a specific CA from an InputStream, uses it to create a KeyStore, which is then used to create and initialize a TrustManager. A TrustManager is what the system uses to validate certificates from the server and—by creating one from a KeyStore with one or more CAs—those will be the only CAs trusted by that TrustManager.
> >     Given the new TrustManager, the example initializes a new SSLContext which provides an SSLSocketFactory you can use to override the default SSLSocketFactory from HttpsURLConnection. This way the connection will use your CAs for certificate validation.
> >     Here is the example in full using an organizational CA from the University of Washington:

```
 // Load CAs from an InputStream
 // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load- der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
URL url = new URL("https://certs.cac.washington.edu/CAtest/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

With a custom TrustManager that knows about your CAs, the system is able to validate that your server certificate come from a trusted issuer.

> > Caution: Many web sites describe a poor alternative solution which is to install a TrustManager that does nothing. If you do this you might as well not be encrypting your communication, because anyone can attack your users at a public Wi-Fi hotspot by using DNS tricks to send your users' traffic through a proxy of their own that pretends to be your server. The attacker can then record passwords and other personal data. This works because the attacker can generate a certificate and—without a TrustManager that actually validates that the certificate comes from a trusted source—your app could be talking to anyone. So don't do this, not even temporarily. You can always make your app trust the issuer of the server's certificate, so just do it.

Comment: The server certificate is issued by Comodo and Chrome said it is trusted.